# ajax infinite scroll - having trouble with post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get infinite scroll to work, and so far I have this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var load = 0;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        load++;
        $('#posts').append(load);
        $.post("includes/ajax.php", {
            load: load
        }, function (data) {
            $('#posts').append(data);
        });
    }
});
```

And here is the contents of ajax.php

```
$load = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['load'])) * 2;

echo $load;
```

I have two problems that I don't really understand. 1. When I append load to #posts directly as a test, it works fine, but it keeps saying 1, 1, 1, instead of adding to itself. 2. When I try to do it using the post ajax to my php file, nothing happens. I followed a video tutorial exactly, but it's not working for me.

Comment: The code itself is working fine, but you have to mention what is your approach. what you want to do with this code and what do you expect from this code?

Answer (score 0):

put the var= 0 outside of the function

Comment: Please add some explanation as to why you submitted this code as an answer - even if it is correct, without an explanation, this answer is not useful to future readers. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation/260413#260413